# Android with only one activity and multiple fragments

Tags: android, events, android-fragments

Sorry for my english,

I've read that between activity or fragment, we should use fragment as soon as we can. Because of that, I was developing my entire app with a lot of fragment and just one activity, switching from one to another with the `beginTransaction().replace()` method. But it seems that I have to implement all my event methods (like onClick) in the activity and not in the fragment. So if I develope everything in only one activity, I will have all my event method on just on class, wich will be unreadable...

I would like to know what is the best thing to do : one activity with a lot of fragment, or multiple activities... how ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An entire app with only one activity and a lot of fragments might not be a very good idea.

If your app functionalities requires it, you can have multiple fragments managed by one activity : supporting tablets and handset / navigation drawer / ViewPager etc.

Anyway, using fragments doesn't force you to code all your event methods in the main activity. Your main activity handles the fragments creation/swaps but most of the actions that you do on a fragment's screen can be coded in the fragment class.

If you want to re-use a fragment in multiple activities it has to be this way.

As said in the google doc :
"You can think of a fragment as a **modular section of an activity**, which has its own lifecycle, **receives its own input events**, and which you can add or remove while the activity is running (sort of like a "sub activity" that you can reuse in different activities)".

The specific code you put in your main activity should be easily refactored in the fragments.

Did you look the official documentation ? There might be some good examples.
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Coding actions in the fragment is very similar to coding them in the activity :

You can handle action bar actions in the fragment :

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
// Inflate your menu
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.option1:
        // Handle option 1
        return true;
    case R.id.option2:
        // Handle option 2
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

You can handle buttons actions in the fragment :

```
Button yourButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.yourbutton);
btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
   // Handle button click
 }
});
```

You can code asynctask in the fragment.

If you have a list, you can code list context menu actions in the fragment :

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    // Inflate your context menu
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.option1:
            // Handle option 1
            return true;
        case R.id.option2:
            // Handle option 2
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

AlertDialog work in a fragment.

Etc. Etc.

Do you have a specific action that gives you trouble refactoring in a fragment ?